# How to use test with the nonzero flag -n

Tags: bash, shell, string-length

I am trying to check out `test` by using the sytax with the brackets `[` and `]`.

The manpage of test says that `-n` can be used to check if the length of  string is not zero:

```
 -n STRING
              the length of STRING is nonzero
```

In the opposite `-z` can be used ti check if the length of a string is zero:

```
-z STRING
              the length of STRING is zero
```

To understand how `test` works I crated an example with an empty variable `foo` which has the length of zero and a second variable `bar` with a length of one:

```
$ export foo
$ export bar=1
$ [ -n $bar ] ; echo $?
0
$ [ -n $foo ] ; echo $?
0
$ [ -z $bar ] ; echo $?
1
$ [ -z $foo ] ; echo $?
0
```

The first two tests with the `-n` are showing both zero as result. I suggested It would be zero for the first test and one for the second. The second test shows the result as suggested.

Comment: Quote your variables or use `[[]]`. `-n $foo` expands to `-n` which as it has no argument is seen by `[ ]` as a string to test with `-n`, so becomes `[ -n "-n" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[ -n "$foo" ] ; echo $?
```

Since the $foo is an empty string, the

```
[ -n $foo ] # without quotes
```

becomes:

```
[ -n ]
```

Manual test(1) says:

```
STRING equivalent to -n STRING
```

So [ -n ] is treated not like [ -n "" ], but like [ "-n" ]